# OLE Automation: How do i copy text between Word documents without using the clipboard

Tags: delphi, automation, clipboard, ole, delphi-xe

While doing som Word automation from Delphi XE, I have two documents open simultaneously. I want to copy the contents of a given range of one document to another range in the other document. How can I do this?

Consider the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.ManipulateDocuments;
var
  vDoc1,vDoc2 : TWordDocument;
  vFilename : olevariant;
  vRange1,vRange2 : Range;
begin
  vDoc1 := TWordDocument.Create(nil);
  vDoc2 := TWordDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    vFilename := 'c:\temp\test1.doc';
    vDoc1.ConnectTo(FWordApp.Documents.Open(vFilename,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam));

    vFilename := 'c:\temp\test2.doc';
    vDoc2.ConnectTo(FWordApp.Documents.Open(vFilename,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam));

    vRange1 := GetSourceRange(vDoc1);
    vRange2 := GetDestinationRange(vDoc2);

    vRange2.CONTENTS := vRange1.CONTENTS; //What should I substitute for CONTENTS?
  finally
    vDoc1.Free;
    vDoc2.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Is there something I could substitute for CONTENTS? I can't use text, since I want to copy formatting, bookmarks, field codes etc.  Do I have to do it another way alltogether? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a way for earlier versions of Word, but for newer versions (2007 and up) you can [export a range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226140%28v=office.12%29.aspx) from a document to a fragment file, and then [import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226143%28v=office.12%29.aspx) it from another document. If you want early binding, you might need to import the type library (msword.olb), I don't know if Delphi XE has it. Otherwise the code might look like this:

```
function GetTempFileName(Prefix: string): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);
  GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, PChar(Result));
  windows.GetTempFileName(PChar(Result), PChar(Prefix), 0, PChar(Result));
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
//  wdFormatDocument = 0;
  wdFormatRTF = $00000006;
var
  WordApp : OleVariant;
  fragment: string;
  vDoc1, vDoc2: OleVariant;
  vRange1, vRange2: OleVariant;
begin
  try
    WordApp := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  end;
  WordApp.Visible := True;

  vDoc1 := WordApp.Documents.Open(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'test1.doc');
  vRange1 := vDoc1.Range(20, 120);     // the export range
  fragment := GetTempFileName('frg');
  vRange1.ExportFragment(fragment, wdFormatRTF);
  try
    vDoc2 := WordApp.Documents.Open(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'test2.doc');
    vRange2 := vDoc2.Range(15, 15);    // where to import
    vRange2.ImportFragment(fragment);
  finally
    DeleteFile(fragment);
  end;
end;
```

With my test, 'document' format threw an error (something like not being able to insert XML formatting), hence usage of RTF format.

**edit:**

With earlier versions, it seems to be possible to insert a named selection from one document to a selection in another document. The result seems not to be perfect regarding formatting if one of the selections happens to be in the middle of some text. But otherwise it seems to be working good.

```
  ...
  WordApp.Visible := True;

  vDoc1 := WordApp.Documents.Open(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'test1.doc');
  vRange1 := vDoc1.Range(20, 188);                 // the transfer range
  vDoc1.Bookmarks.Add('TransferSection', vRange1); // arbitrary bookmark name

  vDoc2 := WordApp.Documents.Open(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'test2.doc');
  vRange2 := vDoc2.Range(103, 104);           // where to import the bookmark
  vRange2.Select;
  vDoc2.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertFile(vDoc1.FullName, 'TransferSection');

  vDoc1.Bookmarks.Item('TransferSection').Delete; // no need for the bookmark anymore
```

Comment: I have noticed these functions (exportfragment/importfragment), and they would be perfect for my need. Unfortunately, Word 2007 is not an option for me. Our solution needs to be available for users running Word 2003, maybe even earlier, where these functions were not available. But thanks anyway. Best suggestion so far :-)

Comment: Update: Since there were no other answers I'll accept this one as the best. Still, it bugs me that there's no good way to do this without involving the clipboard or using external files. It seems so basic :-/

Comment: @Svein - I've updated the answer with an alternative. If it still does not come up satisfactory, I'd suggest adding `msword` to tags and keeping the question unanswered for a while.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)-format (ie. the docx file format that was introduced in Word 2007), then you can do this without automation.

Word versions prior to 2007 must install a [compatibility pack](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/open-a-word-2007-document-in-an-earlier-version-of-word-HA010044473.aspx) which will enable docx-files for Word 2003, 2002 and 2000.

The docx-file is actually a zip-file that contains several xml-files.  Try to change the extension of a docx-file from .docx to .zip and open this file in eg. WinZip.

So...  Unzip docx-file and grab the xml-part you need.  As pure string or as a xml document.  Then you can inject this xml-part into the other docx-file.  You need to know *where* in the xml-structure to grab/insert the xml, though.  This will depend on how well you know the document structure and how much editing the user is allowed to do in the document.

I don't know how Word will handle duplicate bookmark names etc with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the canonical solution to this question while digged into similar problem. The **FormattedText** property of Range object is the exact what do you need. Just use:

```pascal
vRange2.FormattedText := vRange1;
```

and the contents of vRange1 will be copied into vRange2. Also, this works too:

```pascal
vRange2 := vRange1;
```

Though, the second statement doesn't copy the formatting.

Answer (score -3):

Why not use the clipboard? If all the text is selected in vDoc1, then to copy this to the clipboard involves one simple call: vDoc1.copy. Similarly, copying the contents of the clipboard to the second document requires one simple call: vDoc2.paste. The clipboard buffer will hold all the formatting information.

Comment: First of all, if I use the clipboard I will delete whatever the user has put there. Not a good thing to do. Furthermore, this application often runs on a terminal server where the clipboard is synchronized with the local clipboard, causing performance issues.

Comment: -1 The clipboard belongs to the user, not you. You should do absolutely nothing that affects the contents of the clipboard unless the user initiates it (copying or cutting or pasting, for instance).