# Concatenate two Word documents using Delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-word

I would like to combine two word documents into one using Delphi.

In my database I have a table that contains a table with a varbinary(max) that containts a Word document and I would like to create a word document from some of the rows of that table based on a condition.

I have tried using streams

See : [Concatenate TStringStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894908/concatenate-tstringstream/)

Any ideas how can I achieve this? I've been searching, but did not find a solution.

```
var
  i: Int32;
  stream: TFileStream;
  Path1: string;
  WordApp: TWordApplication;
begin
  Path1 := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(GetEnvironmentVariable('TEMP')) +
    FormatDateTime('yyyymmddhhnnssz', Now) + '.doc';
  WordApp := TWordApplication.Create(nil);
  stream := TFileStream.Create(Path1, fmCreate);
  try
    try
      with dm do
      begin
        DataSet.First;
        CopyBlobFieldToStream(dm.DataSet,
          dm.DataSetBlobField, stream);
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(stream.Size));
        DataSet.Next;
        CopyBlobFieldToStream(dm.DataSet,
          dm.DataSetBlobField, stream);
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(stream.Size));
        CopyBlobFieldToStream(dm.DataSet2,
          dm.DataSet2BlobField, stream);
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(stream.Size));
      end;
    finally
      stream.Free;
    end;
    WordApp.Documents.Open(Path1, EmptyParam, False, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
      EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
      EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
    WordApp.Visible := True;
  finally
    WordApp.Free;
  end;
```

This is what i've tried.

Comment: Just an aside, but why use `with dm` and then add `dm.` to most of the enclosed fields? It will be cleaner and safer in the long run to remove the `with`.

Comment: @DavidA it's still in debugging, i've been tried various code lines that's why is like this, i'll refactor it when I have a working solution.

Comment: i think you can not do it by this way. you should save the documents separately, open these files with Delphi separately and copy one content to another one. have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393368/ole-automation-how-do-i-copy-text-between-word-documents-without-using-the-clip

Comment: I think your assumption that concatenating streams is equivalent to concatenating the Word docs they contain is wrong.  It isn't - a Word doc is a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said at your previous question, Word BIFF8 files cannot be simply concatenated. You need a new BIFF8 file to be created that contains the contents of both documents.

Do that using Word automation. Load the first document. Move the selection to the end of that document. Insert the second document at that point. Save the combined document. Here's a very simple example using late bound COM:

```
uses
  ComObj;
....
procedure CombineDocFiles(const input1, input2, output: string);
const
  wdStory = $00000006;
var
  Word, Document: OleVariant;
begin
  Word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  Document := Word.Documents.Open(input1);
  Word.Selection.EndKey(wdStory);
  Word.Selection.InsertFile(input2);
  Document.SaveAs(output);
  Word.Quit;
end;
```

Because I used late bound COM I chose to define `wdStory` explicitly. You could use the `Word2000` unit alternatively. If you did that you could also switch to early bound COM if you would prefer that.

Anyway, I don't really think this question should become a full blown lesson in how to do Word automation. This is just a starter to get you pointing in the right direction.